# how to declare variable by using the following symbol "{!!" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using a ternary operator. Here is my code:

```
<td>
        {!! $cooking->deleted_at ?
        '<button type="button" data-id="{{$cooking->id}}"
            data-target="#restore-CF">Enable</button>'
        :'<button type="button" data-id="{{$cooking->id}}"
          data-target="#exampleModal-3">Disable</button>'!!}
</td>
```

When I inspect by using the chrome developer tool and inspect over the following code `data-id="{{$cooking->id}}"` it shows `<?php echo e($cooking->id); ?>`,

but by inspecting I am suppose to get the value of a number i.e 12.

How to fix this error?

Comment: That is what you are printing. Change data-id="{{$cooking->id}}" to data-id="{{$cooking->deleted_at}}" to print the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove quotes and use blade if statements

```
    @if($cooking->trashed())
      <button type="button" data-id="{{$cooking->id}}"
                data-target="#restore-CF">Enable</button>
    @else
     <button type="button" data-id="{{$cooking->id}}"
              data-target="#exampleModal-3">Disable</button>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Your qustions makes no sense

You should give a condition to check in ternary.

For your easyness, you may write

```
    @if($cooking->deleted_at == 'your_condition_to_check_with')
           <div>Your Statement</div>
    @else
           <div>Your Another Statement</div>
    @endif
```

or, I think you may like to use php isset().

```
    @if(isset($cooking->deleted_at))
```

Your question is very unclear though

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you are writing php and html at the same time and you are not separating the two, to separating php from html, include the php tags

```
<td>
    <?php {!! $cooking->deleted_at ? 
    ' ?><button type="button" data-id="<?php {{$cooking->id}} ?>"
        data-target="#restore-CF">Enable</button><?php'
    :'?><button type="button" data-id="<?php {{$cooking->id}} ?>"
      data-target="#exampleModal-3">Disable</button><?php' !!}?> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove the mustaches on the data-id attribute it would work because you are already in a `{!! !!}` or better still my advice is to use blade syntax by wrapping it in an `@if` and `@else` like so

```
@if($cooking->deleted_at)
    <button type="button" data-id="{{$cooking->id}}" data-target="#restore-CF">Enable</button>
@else
    <button type="button" data-id="{{$cooking->id}}" data-target="#exampleModal-3">Disable</button>
@endif
```

I think this is more readable. I hope this helps.